# Bundling AAC-LD with MPEG2-TS

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, aac, rtsp, mpeg

While using a proprietary SDK I had the following observations:

1) Could hear audio (AAC-LD) and see video (H.264) during the playback of MP4 video file.

2) Could not hear audio (AAC-LD) but could see video (H.264) while live streaming an MPEG2-TS stream via RTSP.

3) Could hear audio (AAC-LC) and see video (H.264) while live streaming an MPEG2-TS stream via RTSP.

Is it possible to bundle AAC-LD + H.264 in a MPEG2-TS container ? In other words, does MPEG2-TS allow the use of AAC-LD audio compression technique ?

PS: I want to decrease the audio latency for two-way talkback kind of application which is why I want to use AAC-LD.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.videolan.org/MPEG/#Accepted_audio_codecs) just suggests that mp4a (aac in general) is supported with no qualifiers. It is odd that it works in one container but not another.

Comment: What is the "proprietary SDK"? Have you asked for support? It is difficult for people to support you without knowing what it is you are using.

Comment: It's a qualcomm SDK that you get as a part of its SOC development kit.

Answer (score 0):

yes, only use

```
-strict -2
```

example

folder

1. audio.mp4 (obviusly in aac for this example)
   2.video.mp4 (in h264)

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 i -audio.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -strict -2 newfile.mp4 or the striming code

to use aac, in some conteneder .like .mp4 .mkv ... is necesary the line **-strict -2** on the end of parameters -map

besos a tu hermana